# What is the wallet password if you press skip when installing

Tags: wallets, password

In the "Protect your account" installer screen there is a "SKIP" link. What is the wallet's password when setting a password is skipped?

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/0*7R66FvJ0aYlXOi65.]

(picture from this guide: https://medium.com/@attores/step-by-step-guide-getting-started-with-ethereum-mist-wallet-772a3cc99af4)